# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am facing issue while parsing JSON using jackson-core-2.7.3.jar
You can get them from here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/

My JSON File is

```
[
    {
        "Name":  "System Idle Process",
        "CreationDate":  "20160409121836.675345+330"
    },
    {
        "Name":  "System",
        "CreationDate":  "20160409121836.675345+330"
    },
    {
        "Name":  "smss.exe",
        "CreationDate":  "20160409121836.684966+330"
    }
]
```

and the Java Code is by which I am trying to parse this is

```
byte[] mapData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("process.txt"));
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
myMap = objectMapper.readValue(mapData, HashMap.class);
System.out.println("Map is: "+myMap);
```

But upon execution I am getting the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [B@34ce8af7; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:873)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:869)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromEmpty(StdDeserializer.java:874)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:337)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2872)
```

I have tried searching over stackoverflow but couldnot find a matchable solution to this type of JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

> NOTE: This `JSON` mentioned here is different a `JSON` without `Key` , for the first element it has value directly and inside that value it has `key:value`pair. 
>   I am not sure how do I access `key:value` pair which is inside a value.

Comment: How do you expect a JSON array to be converted to a Java `HashMap`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error converting JSON string to map in Java using Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018340/error-converting-json-string-to-map-in-java-using-jackson)

Comment: Its not duplicate you should check JSON first and read the problem properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a simple `pojo` Class First

```
class MyClass
{
@JsonProperty
private String Name;
@JsonProperty
private String CreationDate;
}
```

and use this code...

```
byte[] mapData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("process.txt"));

ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
//add this line  
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);    
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(mapData , new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

or

```
byte[] mapData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("process.txt"));

ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
 //add this line  
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);    

List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(mapData , mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyClass.class));
```

`myObjects` will contains the `List` of `MyClass`. Now you can access this list as per your requirement.

Comment: Please go through the JSON file again
Creating class MyClass wont work with this JSON.
I need to know how do I write as it is a JSON without name

Comment: what  should i look into ?  @AshishPatel

Comment: The JSON file is value->key:value pair
It doesnt have 1st level key pair if you look into it.
So even if i create class MyClass upon execution it throws error Unrecognized field "Name"

Comment: have you tried yet or not? just try if error came then only you should  say. please try one test case atleast. @AshishPatel

Comment: @AshishPatel That's why you convert to a `List<MyClass>` not to `MyClass`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it
Here is the error 
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Name" (class testapps.MyProcess), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

Comment: @AshishPatel add getters and setters to your `testapps.MyProcess` class or add `@JsonProperty` above `Name` and `CreationDate` fields like this: `class MyProcess {
        @JsonProperty
        private String Name;
        @JsonProperty
        private String CreationDate;
    }`

Comment: @AshishPatel I have edited my answer .. would you please try this code??

Comment: @varren It gives output like testapps.MyProcess@60addb54
testapps.MyProcess@3f2a3a5
testapps.MyProcess@4cb2c100

Comment: @varren You are great man It works! :) I created getter and setter methods after that

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Thanks a lot, I have been struggling with this whole day, this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 27):

**This exception is raised because you're trying to deserialize a `List` in a `Map`.**

The solution is create a TypeReference of `List<Map<String, Object>>`:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myObjects = 
          mapper.readValue(mapData , new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but How can we check whether the file is returning List or Map.
As the above solution will fail for map.

Answer (score 11):

It seem's that your file is representing a List of objects with **Name** and **CreationDate** fields.

So you have to just use List instead of HashMap to ObjectMapper, code is mentioned below:

```
List<HashMap> dataAsMap = objectMapper.readValue(mapData, List.class);
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, you are trying to convert an **json string** that contains **array/list of objects** into an **object**.

Ex: `{ "key": "value"}` is the json you want to convert, but actually you are doing,

`[{ "key": "value"}]`.

simple fix, is remove the first and last char from your string and try. Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 3):

Why not?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Object obj = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Object>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not a Map, but a List of Maps. So replace this:

```
myMap = objectMapper.readValue(mapData, HashMap.class);
```

with this:

```
myMap = objectMapper.readValue(mapData, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, String>>>(){});
```

Or you can change the format of your JSON data...